# Visual Studio 2017 and Razor Version

Tags: visual-studio, razor

I'm just starting to learn MVC and have loaded the new VS2017. When I try to open a new ASP.NET Website it only shows (Razor v3). The tutorial I'm following is using (Razor v4). How or where do a download this version? Thanks

Comment: There is no Razor v4 as of this moment in time.  Perhaps you are thinking of MVC v4.

Comment: Thanks Sam. I see that now. Sorry for being a dumb a**.